# How to sort DataFrame columns sequently from the first column?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, correlation

I sorted df columns by max value of rows.

```
dff = centroids.reindex(df.sum().sort_values(ascending=False).index, axis=1)

print(dff)

    13        9         2         6         7         0         5
0   0.423586  0.472548  0.366301  0.423973  0.312807  0.476197  0.384652   
1   0.639636  0.734712  0.503772  0.600164  0.416451  0.730942  0.515370
2   0.749716  0.835071  0.549806  0.637331  0.419558  0.782306  0.507648
3   0.817579  0.844361  0.577874  0.621483  0.408825  0.727671  0.458346   
4   0.890916  0.831640  0.631127  0.611741  0.438974  0.654338  0.430330
5   0.952046  0.802077  0.694321  0.601616  0.496798  0.572743  0.423915
6   0.995009  0.768293  0.749186  0.590912  0.553378  0.500568  0.427607   
7   1.000000  0.718386  0.781207  0.570253  0.598234  0.425387  0.436355   
8   0.993004  0.690660  0.779607  0.550149  0.600459  0.396121  0.422891
```

Now i need sort this columns by correlation between each other, but perform this sequently. So define second column by best correlation with first, define third column by best correlation with second and so on. 
And also i want to save original labels of columns

I have some thoughts about that, but because i am newbie in python code not work

```
k_num = 7 # number of columns in df
def corelation(df):
   col = 1
   for column in dff.columns[col:]:
       dff.reindex(dff.corr().sort_values(dff.columns[col], ascending=False).index, axis = 1)
   col += 1
   if col == k_num:
      return(df)
```

I will be very appreciate if some help me

Comment: Hello! What is dff in your code? And why don't you use column iterator in your for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a list that will hold the required order of columns. Let's call it `l` and initially populate it with the first column `0`. Then we iteratively find the max correlation between the column stored as the last element in `l` and the subset of the DataFrame that excludes columns that are already in `l`, adding on each step the new column with max correlation to the list `l`. When there are no more columns left, `l` will hold the required order of columns, and `df[l]` will give us the DataFrame with columns sorted by max correlation:

```
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 10))

l = [0]
while len(l) < len(df.columns):
    i = df[df.columns.difference(l)].corrwith(df[l[-1]]).abs().idxmax()
    l += [i]

df[l]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer you defenetly understand what i want to do, but your solution gives me back on my df "TypeError: other must be a MultiIndex or a list of tuples"

Comment: Can you share `df.columns` output please?

Comment: Not sure if your column names are strings or integers. If they are strings you can try initializing l with `l = ['0']` (so enclosing the number in quotes) before the `while` loop

Comment: I tried with the ['0'] but it writes error  "an integer is required"

Comment: Something is not right, I can read your file with `df = pd.read_csv('df_damir.csv').drop('Unnamed: 0', 1)` and then run the exact script as above with no error, only changing to `l = ['0']` because when I read from the file with `read_csv` column names are read as strings